# what is the minimal record overhead in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

Let's say we have a simple setup where we funnel event batches through Topic1, consuming them in a worker to break them apart and republish to Topic2.  Our batches are max 1000 events, and in some cases we see our downstream Topic2 being 5x the size of Topic1.

I am wondering how much data accompanies the payload for a single record in a kafka topic, in the simplest case with no special headers? And should this extra overhead of a record per event result in 5x the data footprint for a given data set?

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete message format for a produced record [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-ProduceRequest). You shouldn't see 5x more data. I'd suggest consuming some messages with the console consumer to see what's being added to the messages.